# "Intellisense" not available inside a function

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am trying to parse/process an XML document within QTP. What is the correct way to pass objects to functions so that Intellisense can deduce the object type and show the methods and properties of the object?

I have my VBScript code as follows (in the QTP editor):

```
' Define the variable globally 
Set oldInsuranceNode = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
:
:
:' Lots of intervening code here
:
Set oldInsuranceNode = objOldNodeList.item(0).childNodes.item(oldFileIndex)    
oldInsuranceNode.childNodes.Count
'After the "." in oldInsuranceNode, I get the relevant functions, properties
'of the oldInsuranceNode object like childNodes, insertBefore etc. 
'(I believe it is of type IXMLDOMElement).
'Call the function                                                                                                                                                                                 
ConstructInsuranceSubNodesDictionary oldInsuranceNode, newInsuranceNode    
:
:

Function ConstructInsuranceSubNodesDictionary(nodeC, NodeD)
nodeC.childNodes.Count
'However, after the . after nodeC , I am not getting the help similar to 
'oldInsuranceNode above. The code "compiles" so to speak and it even works 
'but I am forced to use oldInsuranceNode to get Intellisense ....
'which works !
```

The editor is not able to deduce the type within the function if it is a different name even though I am passing in the object correctly. What is the correct way to avail of the Intellisense within the function block too and not use the global variable that is set at the start?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34533690/1630171). Seems to be a limitation of the IDE. The last comment to that other question has a link that might help.

Comment: Ah, thanks ! Nothing we can do abt that I guess.